# JOIN two tables but only return rows from Table 1 that match Table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Good day 
I have two tables I need to Join , `Transfer Excise` Tbl and `Value Entry`.

**Transfer Excise Tbl:** No must match the Item no in the Value Entry table. I did do a comparison for Items not in Transfer Excise that is in Value entry and found a few.

Transfer Excise Tbl:

```
Starting Date           No_                  Excise Location Location Code Unit Rate                               Excise Type Code Unit Of Measure Code Litre Conversion Factor
----------------------- -------------------- --------------- ------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------
2013-02-28 00:00:00.000 600011263            NONBOND         ~DUTY PAID    2.70000000000000000000                  UWNEPACK         LITRES               1.33333000000000000000  
2014-02-27 00:00:00.000 600011263            NONBOND         ~DUTY PAID    2.87000000000000000000                  UWNEPACK         LITRES               1.33333000000000000000  
2015-02-26 00:00:00.000 600011263            NONBOND         ~DUTY PAID    3.07000000000000000000                  UWNEPACK         LITRES               1.33333000000000000000  
2016-02-25 00:00:00.000 600011263            NONBOND         ~DUTY PAID    3.31000000000000000000                  UWNEPACK         LITRES               1.33333000000000000000
```

Value Entry Table:

```
Item No_             Location Code Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group Invoiced Quantity
-------------------- ------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
F00330               VINI          EXSA                    -10.00000000000000000000  
F00331               VINI          EXSA                    -30.00000000000000000000  
F00332               VINI          EXSA                    -40.00000000000000000000
```

I want to write the query to exclude duplicates as the script below still creates duplicates. The PK is Item No and the FK is Location Code. you will see on the Transfer excise table that for each year I new unit rate was supplied for a specific Item and Location

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[Starting Date],  
    b.[Posting Date], 
    b.[Item No_],  
    b.[Invoiced Quantity],  
    a.[Litre Conversion Factor], 
    a.[Unit Rate] , 
    a.[Location Code],  
    a.[Excise Location], 
    a.[Excise Type Code], 
    a.[Unit Of Measure Code]
FROM [Transfer Excise Tbl] a JOIN [Spier Live$Value Entry] b
ON a.[No_] = b.[Item No_] 
WHERE  b.[Posting Date] > '2013-02-26 '
AND b.[Location Code] = a.[Location Code]
AND b.[Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group] IN ('LOCA','EXSA')
AND b.[Posting Date] >= a.[Starting Date]
AND b.[Invoiced Quantity] <>0
```

Comment: Can you add some DDL and post expected result.I could not inline those images since images are blocked in my domain.Can you inline them.

Comment: "Transfer Excise Tbl: No must match the Item no in the Value Entry table": looks to me like the join is doing exactly that.  What's the problem?

Comment: @Kevin  i get more rows than expected as my end result in Navision give me different amount of rows

Comment: @Kevin ,There is No's in the Transfer Excise Tbl that does not match the Item no's in Value Entry and there is Item No's in Value Entry that does not match No's in Transfer Excise Tbl. If the numbers do not match it gives a NULL value which means no transaction for that Item. I need to avoid the NULLS

Comment: @Kevin , i did a DDL to show you my end result what i need to get , how can i paste it on this page so that you can view it

Comment: @TheGameiswar, anyone that can assist me

Comment: Select "Results as Text" before running your query.  You'll be able to copy and paste the results here in reasonably readable form.

Comment: @Kevin , I have edited my question and removed the images and replaced it with my result in text format

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is something wrong with your [Value Entry] table.

1) In your query you refer to [Posting Date] column, but there is no such column in your example data.

Now, if I have well understood the scenario, I think your problem is related to how you join lines from the two tables.

I get more lines than you expect because you JOIN each line in [Value Entry] with ALL lines in [Transfer Excise Tbl] with a [Starting Date] older, not only the LAST (valid) line.

To solve the problem you should pre-calc the period of validity of your [Transfer Excise Tbl] line finding the [End Date] of each line, and then you will
JOIN b.[Posting Date] **BETWEEN** a.[Starting Date] **AND** a.[End Date]

final query will be something like:

```
;WITH
EndDates as (-- add [End Date] to [Transfer Excise Tbl]
    select t1.*, ISNULL([End Date], CONVERT(date, '9999-12-31', 121)) [End Date]
    from [Transfer Excise Tbl] t1
    outer apply (
        select MIN([Starting Date]) [End Date]
        from [Transfer Excise Tbl]
        where [Starting Date] > t1.[Starting Date]
    ) T2
)
SELECT DISTINCT a.[Starting Date],  
    b.[Posting Date], 
    b.[Item No_],  
    b.[Invoiced Quantity],  
    a.[Litre Conversion Factor], 
    a.[Unit Rate] , 
    a.[Location Code],  
    a.[Excise Location], 
    a.[Excise Type Code], 
    a.[Unit Of Measure Code]
FROM [EndDates] a JOIN [Spier Live$Value Entry] b ON a.[No_] = b.[Item No_] AND b.[Posting Date] BETWEEN a.[Starting Date] AND a.[End Date]
WHERE  b.[Posting Date] > '2013-02-26 '
AND b.[Location Code] = a.[Location Code]
AND b.[Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group] IN ('LOCA','EXSA')    
AND b.[Invoiced Quantity] <> 0
```

It should return only the number of rows you expect

I hope this helps